# Dictionary and interface of multiple constrained generic types

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics, interface

I am converting a Java project to C# and i am getting in trouble with the following:

IMessageHandler

```
 public interface IMessageHandler<T, H> where T : IPeerAttachment where H : IMessage {
    void HandleMessage(T clientAttachment, H message);
}
```

LoginRequestHandler

```
public class LoginRequestHandler : IMessageHandler<LoginPeerAttachment , LoginRequest> {
    public void HandleMessage(LoginPeerAttachment clientAttachment, LoginRequest message) {

    }
}
```

MessageHandlerRegistry

```
 private readonly Dictionary<MessageId, IMessageHandler<IPeerAttachment, IMessage>> _handlers = new Dictionary<MessageId, IMessageHandler<IPeerAttachment, IMessage>>();
```

What i would like to do is following:

```
LoginRequestHandler loginRequestHandler = new LoginRequestHandler();
_handlers[messageId] = loginRequestHandler;
```

This gives me an compile error telling me that it need to be of type IMessageHandler.

I am not sure why this do not work since LoginRequestHandler implements only derived types of what is specified in interface.

Any suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: You might have to rethink this, `IMessageHandler<T, H>` will need to be *covariant* i.e `IMessageHandler<out T, out H>` to be assignable from `LoginRequestHandler`. however you are then stuck by losing your contact   `void HandleMessage(T clientAttachment, H message);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is disallowed because its not type safe. Huh? How can the following not be type safe:

```
var _handlers = new Dictionary<MessageId, IMessageHandler<IPeerAttachment, IMessage>>();
var loginRequestHandler = new LoginRequestHandler();
_handlers[messageId] = loginRequestHandler;
```

`LoginRequestHandler` is a `IMessageHandler<IPeerAttachment, IMessage>` so what is wrong here?

Well, lets say the previous were legal, and take it a step further and see what happens:

```
var handler = _handlers[meesageId];
handler.HandleMessage(logOutPeerAttachment, logOutMessage);
```

Is that legal? Well, it sure looks like it. `handler` is of type `IMessageHandler<IPeerAttachment, IMessage>` and therefore `HandleMessage` can handle the supplied argument types...

So, now we've come to a horrible situation; following perfectly legal steps, we've just broken the type system because somehow we've asked a `LoginRequestHandler` to handle a `LogOutRequest`.

Obviously, as you've painfully experienced first hand, not all steps are legal; this reference conversion is in fact illegal: `(IMessageHandler<IPeerAttachment, IMessage>)loginRequestHandler`

In order for this conversion to work, the type variance of `IMessageHandler` would need to be covariant which means, generic arguments can only go out, not in (its a bit more convoluted than that but it gets the idea across). Canonical example? `IEnumerable<out T>`? Why? Because there is no way to input a `T` in an `IEnumerable<T>` , therefore this is legal:

```
var tigers = new List<Tiger>();
IEnumerable<Animal> animals = tigers;
```

But this isn't:

```
var tigers = new List<Tiger>();
List<Animal> animals = tigers;
```

In your scenario, a covariant interface doesn't seem to be a choice so you probably need to reconsider your approach. You seem to be trying to express too much in your type system to the point that's its fighting against you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I´ll go back and rethink this.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is fundamentally incompatible with a type system that isn't unsound with respect to generic variance like the Java type system is.

If you were able to assign a `LoginRequestHandler` to a variable of type `IMessageHandler<IPeerAttachment, IMessage>` then you would be able to call the `HandleMessage` method with any types derived from `IPeerAttachment` and `IMessage`, thus causing a runtime error.